# 307 redirect rule with Microsoft Rewrite Module 2.0

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Is it possible to make a 307 redirect rule in web.config with Microsoft Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7? The goal is to redirect some post form requests to another path within the same domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set **redirectType** attribute of action **tag** to **"Temporary"**

Eg.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newdomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.old-domain\.com" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```